# codeigniter show image on header

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, codeigniter-3

I used session data. But I wnat to do sessiondata = something on DB. For example

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="<?php
                    if(($this->session->userdata('people_id')) == 'cosId') { echo base_url().'upload/customer/'.$this->session->userdata('people_img');} else{ echo base_url().'upload/user/'.$this->session->userdata('people_img');} ?>">
                    <span class="username"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('people_name'); ?>  <?php echo $this->session->userdata('people_surname'); ?></span>
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
```

How can I do that `(($this->session->userdata('people_id')) == 'cosId')` for show any image in other directories about sessiondata?

When customer login can see own photo or when user login can see own photo from different image directory / root directory.

My controller with userdata is below:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $user_data = $this->db->get_where('user', array('userUsername' =>$username,'userPass' => $password));
            $cus_data = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('cosUserName' =>$username,'cosPassword' => $password));
            if ($user_data->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($user_data->result_array() as $row) {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_id',$row['userId']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_name',$row['userName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_surname',$row['userSurname']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_usertype',$row['userType']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_username',$row['userUsername']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_img',$row['userImg']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_email',$row['userEmail']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_status',$row['userStatus']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_cdate',$row['userDate']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_department',$row['userDepartment']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_lang',$row['userLang']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata("logged_in", true);
                }
                // redirect to dashboard
                redirect("dashboard");
            }
            elseif ( $cus_data->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($cus_data->result_array() as $row) {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_id',$row['cusId']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_name',$row['cosName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_surname',$row['cosSurname']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_username',$row['cosUserName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_img',$row['cosImg']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_cname',$row['cosCName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_country',$row['cosCountry']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_email',$row['cosEmail']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_status',$row['cosStatus']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_lang',$row['cosLang']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata("logged_in", true);
```

Can I edit like that for customers?

```
<?php $cus_data = $this->db->get_where('customer');
                    foreach ($cus_data->result_array() as $row) {

                    if($this->session->set_userdata('people_id',$row['cusId']))
                    {
                        $src = base_url('upload/customer/'.$this->session->userdata('people_img'));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $src = base_url('upload/user/'.$this->session->userdata('people_img'));
                    }}
                    ?>
```

Login Method Currently:

```
public function index(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("username", "Username", "trim|required");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required");
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", validation_errors());
            $this->load->view("login");
        }
        else{
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $user_data = $this->db->get_where('user', array('userUsername' =>$username,'userPass' => $password));
            $cus_data = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('cosUserName' =>$username,'cosPassword' => $password));
            if ($user_data->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($user_data->result_array() as $row) {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_id',$row['userId']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_name',$row['userName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_surname',$row['userSurname']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_usertype',$row['userType']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_username',$row['userUsername']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_img',$row['userImg']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_email',$row['userEmail']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_status',$row['userStatus']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_cdate',$row['userDate']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_department',$row['userDepartment']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_lang',$row['userLang']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata("logged_in", true);
                }
                // redirect to dashboard
                redirect("dashboard");
            }
            elseif ( $cus_data->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($cus_data->result_array() as $row) {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_id',$row['cusId']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_name',$row['cosName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_surname',$row['cosSurname']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_username',$row['cosUserName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_img',$row['cosImg']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_cname',$row['cosCName']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_country',$row['cosCountry']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_email',$row['cosEmail']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_status',$row['cosStatus']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('people_lang',$row['cosLang']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata("logged_in", true);
                }
                // redirect to dashboard
                redirect("dashboard");
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "Username or Password is invalid");
                $this->load->view("login");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error u get?

Comment: I dont get any error. Just no image on header when customer login.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The condition looks okay, so what does not work yet?

Comment: I want to show when customer login, customer see own picture from customer directory or when user login, user can see own picture from user directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do something like this :**

**Firs way :** 
In your login method set a `session` for image `url` also

For Customer :

```
$cust_src = base_url('upload/customer/'.$row['cusImg']);
$this->session->set_userdata('image_src',$cust_src);
```

For User :

```
$user_src = base_url('upload/customer/'.$row['userImg']);
$this->session->set_userdata('image_src',$user_src);
```

And your anchor img should be like this :

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
     <img alt="" src="<?=$this->session->userdata('image_src');;?>">
     <span class="username"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('people_name'); ?>  <?php echo $this->session->userdata('people_surname'); ?></span>
     <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

**Second way do like this  :**

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('people_id') == 'cosId') 
    {
        $src = base_url('upload/customer/'.$this->session->userdata('people_img'));
    }
    else
    {
        $src = base_url('upload/user/'.$this->session->userdata('people_img'));
    }
    ?>

    <img alt="" src="<?php echo $src;?>" >
    <span class="username"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('people_name'); ?>  <?php echo $this->session->userdata('people_surname'); ?>

    </span>
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

Comment: No I cannot see customer image. cosId is a field from customer table on DB. Can I equal this correct you think? ($this->session->userdata('people_id') == 'cosId')

Comment: ya if the session value matches with your db customer_id it will surely show you the result, make sure both are same

Comment: image path is correct. I added my controller part of userdata on top.

Comment: little confusion ,what will be your session if both `$cus_data` and `$user_data` has data

Comment: How I do that?.

Comment: i think you should have a `category` field in both table by which u can identify which `user` is logged in if `category` is `customer` it will be customer data  and if category is `user` then it will be user data

Comment: Not It doesn't.

Comment: An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_pdo_mysql_driver::num_rows() Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\application\controllers\Login.php Line Number: 30 Backtrace: File: C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once

Comment: and where is the line number 30 in login.php, show with comment

Comment: I changed code to old style And error has been ok. I can't do what you say to "little confusion ,what will be your session if both $cus_data and $user_data has data" . Can you show it how it is?

Comment: no i said it because then i have not seen your code in login.php

Comment: No I have no error to show the images but no image of customer.